Why isn't my Frontend Showing but my backend is accessible via NGINX?
I'm trying to deploy a website with a React frontend and Node.js backend, the backend is accessible from my VPS I can make requests to it but my frontend after SEVERE research won't show and I can't figure out why.
I have this
root@srv597605:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# vi /etc/nginx/sites-available/brava-app.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my_server_name;

    root /var/www/brava/frontend/build;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$is_args&$query_string;
    }

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

And my build files are in here /var/www/brava/frontend/build
root@srv597605:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# ls /var/www/brava/frontend/build
asset-manifest.json  brava-black.png  brava.png  favicon.ico  index.html  logo512.png  manifest.json  robots.txt  static
root@srv597605:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled#

I can access the backend through the VPSs IP and make requests, but my frontend always displays a 404 page not found
Deploy Create-React-App on Nginx didn't work for me...
